# C# silent printing with Google Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I've been searching for a long time whether I could make google chrome to print specific html doc via C# app. Unfortunately I didn't find an answer. So, is there any way to print html docs with GC but not with IE? p.s. Thank for any answer

```
namespace testPritn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void PrintHelpPage()
        {
            // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
            WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

            // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
            webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
                new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

            // Set the Url property to load the document.
            webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"D:\test.html");
        }

        private void PrintDocument(object sender,
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
            ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

            // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
            ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintHelpPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WebBrowser is a wrapper around Internet Explorer only.  Check out the CefRef project with .NET bindings at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.  You can use NuGet to install it into your application `Install-Package CefSharp.WinForms`